# Problems with connecting a client to my SSH tunnel (Windows 7)

Tags: ssh, cygwin, tunnel

As topic, I have set up my home computer as an SSH server with Cygwin. I am able to connect from my internal network, and port 22 is open for traffic, so that shouldn't be an issue. However, the client I am trying to connect with, is seemingly behind a firewall because port 22 is not open on that computer. It runs in a big corporate work network, so I can't port forward any ports on it. It does have connection to web browsers, can use both Skype with it, but I can't connect to my server. I'll basically use it just for steam, as it is blocked it seems on the work network. Is it anyway to get around it, or to force steam to use any other connections or ports?

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you confirmed that your ssh server is accessible from outside your home network?
2. Run your ssh server on port 443 or port 80. The firewall you are behind porbably allows connections to these ports (secure web and web)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, wrong IP on the client, that's it :p